# Special arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, database, data-structures

this is the input array

```
Array= [{Client: 1, Budget: 520, Name: "Oscar"},{Client: 2, Budget: 430, Name: "Jane"}]
```

Hi, is there anyway to access this array in that way:

```
print(Array[0])
```

=> {Client: 1, Budget: 520, Name: "Oscar"}

```
print(Array[0][Budget])
```

=> 520

I have checked with dictionaries but apparently dictionaries requires " " ie *{Name: "Oscar"}* should be *{'Name':"Oscar"}* which is not out input

Comment: Are ```Client```, ```Budget``` etc..  variables or strings?

Comment: this is api response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an inconsistency in your input data. First of all, let's consider that this is an array of dictionaries, so index access is allowed.

According to your example: Client, Budget and Name are pre-defined variables. In that case you can access but using a value behind, which in my opinion leads to a design error.

Anyway I will show you an example:

```
Client = 'client'
Budget = 'budget'
Name = 'name'

Array= [{Client: 1, Budget: 520, Name: "Oscar"},{Client: 2, Budget: 430, Name: "Jane"}]
```

Now you can access the data the way you wanted.

```
print(Array[0])
```

> {Client: 1, Budget: 520, Name: "Oscar"}

```
print(Array[0][Budget])
```

> 520

Consider using quotes in key names to avoid unnecessary references.